Create CRM Analytics and CPQ Enabled Developer Edition
I usually drop a query here if I don't have answers anywhere else.
Problem statement: I want to create some use cases that involves the usage of cpq and crma (crma analytics). Salesforce allows only one kind to create at once.
CPQ: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/promo/orgs/cpqtrails
CRMA: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/promo/orgs/analytics-de
Looking for: Any other way I can achieve this if I want crma reporting on cpq objects in one developer org.

Could you accomplish your requirements in a Scratch org?  I'm not familiar with CRMA, but it is definitely possible to create a CPQ-capable scratch and to install the package.  I looks like there are a number of CRMA-related features which can be enabled in a scratch org: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm.

@JasonClark Let me try that. There's a catch I believe, that I can have crma feature but won't be able to create recipes. But let me confirm by trying it out once again. THanks

@JasonClark Could you please add your comment as answer? I was able to install both crma + cpq in a scratch org successfully. Thank you! There were many hit and trials but was able to install both :D

will share the process as a comment in your answer.

Instead of a developer org, try a scratch org.  Scratch orgs are highly configurable, and are designed to be declarative and reproduceable.
I'm not familiar with CRMA, but it is definitely possible to create a CPQ-capable scratch and to install the package. I looks like there are a number of CRMA-related features which can be enabled in a scratch org; see Scratch Org Features in the CLI docs for a full list.

As suggested, I installed a scratch org with project-scratch json file defined as   "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi", "InsightsPlatform", "CoreCpq", "CPQ", "CustomerExperienceAnalytics", "EinsteinAnalyticsPlus", "DevelopmentWave", "AnalyticsAdminPerms", "AnalyticsAppEmbedded"]. Secondly, installed the https://steelbrick.my.site.com/apex/installPremium for the CPQ on my sandbox (created as scratch org from my devHub). VOila! Thanks @jason
